# Ambiguous nature of capturing optional groups in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the input string "A-B-Z".

Regex `([A-Z-]*)(-Z)?` matches "A-B-Z" as group 1 and nothing as group 2. I'd expect "A-B" and "-Z", but seems like the optionality of the second group prevents that from happening. If I make the last group non-optional like `([A-Z-]*)(-Z)`, group 1 is "A-B" and group 2 is "-Z" as expected. But I don't know if my inputs are going to have that optional piece. How do I make it optional while still allowing it to capture when it's provided?

Also, `([A-Z]*)(-Z)?` (no "-" allowed in the first group) works as expected for an input like "ABC-Z". The possibility of "-" in the first group seems to create ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot ChatGPT was a thing. It was able to solve this :)

`([A-Z-]*?)(-Z)`. The "*?" in the first capture group means non-greedy, so it doesn't consume the part I want to be in the second group.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: The answer is my own wording, and I verified it. CGPT just pointed me in the right direction on this.